# Java XMLType file modification

Tags: java, xml, database, oracle, xmltype

I loaded an XMLType file from Oracle DB into Java app. I prepared a class to handle operations on XML file which looks like this:

```
public class XMLDoc {
private OraclePreparedStatement stmt;
private ResultSet rset;
private OracleResultSet orset;
private Document xml_column;
private XMLType poxml;

public XMLDoc(Connection con, String Query) throws Exception {
    setStmt((OraclePreparedStatement)
            con.prepareStatement(Query));
    setRset(getStmt().executeQuery());
    setOrset((OracleResultSet) rset);
}}
```

And in main program I connect to a database and read XML file into xml_column:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
tables[5] = (new XMLDoc(con, "SELECT p.PENALITESXML FROM PENALITES p WHERE id_order='"+data.getIdOrder()+"'"));
while(tables[5].getOrset().next()) {
            tables[5].setPoxml(XMLType.createXML(tables[5].getOrset().getOPAQUE("PENALITESXML")));
            tables[5].setXml_column((Document)tables[5].getPoxml().getDocument());
            Element element = tables[5].getXml_column().getDocumentElement();}
```

Now, I'd like to modify loaded XML doc, so I perform:

```
tables[5].getXml_column().getElementsByTagName("ISPAID").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).setNodeValue("Y");
```

But the document isn't updated. What am I doing wrong?

This is how the XML file looks like:

```
<PENALITES ID_ORDER="50000">
    <PENALTY_AMOUNT>100</PENALTY_AMOUNT>
    <ISPAID>N</ISPAID>
</PENALITIES>
```

Comment: Is the aim to change the XML and update the database with this change? If so, why use Java at all - just modify the XML in the database.

Comment: I know there are other ways like XPath or XQuery but I need to modify it inside app using DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the replacements very simply in the SQL you send to Oracle:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
tables[5] = new XMLDoc(
  con,
  "SELECT UPDATEXML( XMLType( PENALITESXML ), '/PENALTIES/ISPAID/text()', 'Y' ).getStringVal()"
  + " AS PENALTIESXML"
  + " FROM PENALITES"
  + " WHERE id_order='"+data.getIdOrder()+"'"
);
```

You should also consider using bind variables in your prepared statements.

Comment: ok but that's xpath approach. how to do it with DOM approach?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
There is a method `setTextContent()` which must be used instead of `setNodeValue()`
.

```
tables[5].getXml_column().getElementsByTagName("ISPAID").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).setTextContent("Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

updateXML has been deprecated. You should try and use the XQUERY-UPDATE facility and the XMLQUERY operators